# SQL - how to search for double occuring record with different column?

Tags: sql

SQL newbie here. I have a table which looks like that:

[image: SQL table]

I want to get product_id of records, which are present in table two times: one with variant_id X, variant_id Y. In shown screenshot, the result would be product_id = 5106 (because it exists with two variant_id = 19607 and 19608).

However, I have no idea how to do this. I tried using statement WHERE variant_id IN(19607,19608), but it returns any record that has one of those IDs set. I also tried WHERE variant_id = 19607 AND variant_id = 19608, but it returns nothing (pretty understandable, as one record cannot have two variant_ids).

What SQL keyword should I use? Or I need a special combination of these? Thank you very much for answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do aggregation :

```
select product_id
from table t
where variant_id in (19607, 19608)
group by product_id
having min(variant_id) <> max(variant_id);
```

If you want all columns then you can use `exists` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.product_id = t.product_id and t1.variant_id  = 19607) and
      exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.product_id = t.product_id and t1.variant_id  = 19608);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
select product_id
from t
where variant_id in (19607, 19608)
group by product_id
having count(distinct variant_id) = 2;
```

Comment: Oh, I had to use "having" keyword! That's what I missed. Thank you very much, it worked :)